# Linux Debian как войти в систему с root правами?

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, root

В VirtualBox установил  Linux Debian , хотел бы входить в систему сразу с root правами. Через bash root получаю без проблем. Но меня интересует root именно в графической среде. При входе даёт выбрать только созданного мной польователя(не root).

PS мне нужно это для свободного удаления программ и получения доступа к общей папке в графической среде между windows и virtualbox linux. Везде отказано в доступе.. требуют root права.
Когда добавил папку и пользователя в одну группу, то открыть её удалось, но файлы в ней не отобразились(пусто). Хотя в windows они там есть.

Comment: Не нужно этого хотеть. Нужно разобраться как правильно расшарить общую папку.

Comment: я новичёк в Linux, но заметил что куда не плюнь в настройках везде требуются root права.. а так как привык к графическому интерфейсу, то очень хотелось бы их получить, чтобы свободно делать всё не настраивая постоянно отдельно для всего доступ через bash

Comment: но конечно и папку тоже интересно как расшарить, уже пересмотрел и ютуб и гуглил, всё делаю как там сказано, но результат совсем не тот получается.. не понимаю почему так..

Comment: `для свободного удаления программ` - используйте sudo. `получения доступа к общей папке в графической среде` - скорее всего замонтировали куда-то не туда. Выберите каталог монтирования как /home/user/share например, то есть в хомяк. Для решения проблемы пишите детали, что там у вас никому не понятно. Куда монтируете? Какая файловая система на хосте? Рут привилегии вам не нужны, разберитесь, а не хотите разбираться - вам скорее всего и Linux не подойдет

Comment: У меня в минте всё отлично работало. Когда надо, права запрашивались.

Comment: Заведите еще одного пользователя (рутом) с uid = 0. Вот и все...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всем спасибо, разобрался. Достаточно было добавить в группу sudo своего пользователя, для получения полного контроля, как у root. А для расшаривания папки требовалось установить заголовки и дополнения из гостевой ОС.

Answer (score 1):

При выборе пользователя нажмите "не в списке" ("not listed") введите root и пароль. Но скорее всего вы случайно убьёте систему в течении месяца. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пробовал, под рутом не входит таким способом.. пишет пароль не подходит, хотя пароль правильный, через консоль вхожу по нему без проблем

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно просто ввести "root" "root-password" в окне логина. Лично у себя я с Kali легко могу это сделать... Ну или добавьте пользователя в группу sudo/wheel (на разных ОС-ях чуть по разному называется эта группа) и все)

Comment: при входе в систему при вводе логина root и пароля от него заходить не хочет